# Problem with React Native sliding up panel and keyboard avoiding view

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-native

I have a component inside my sliding up Panel which contains various text inputs and I haven't used any keyboard avoiding view but my content automatically slides up when I try to type something in the text input in my sliding up panel.
I need to figure out some ways to disable the automatic sliding up of my sliding up panel when I try to input something in my input field.

```
<SlidingUpPanel resizeToAvoidBottomInset={false} friction={0.03} ref={c => 
this._panel = c} height={height}
draggableRange={{ top: height / 1.3, bottom: 0 }}
onBottomReached={() => {
      this.setState({ showPlusIcon: true })
}}
>
    <ExpensesEntry onPress1={() => {
      this._panel.hide()
    }}  
    onPress={() => {
         this._panel.hide()
         this.setState({ showPlusIcon: true })
         this.props.expenses_store();
             setTimeout(() => {
                 this.apiCalls()
             }, 2000);
    }} />
</SlidingUpPanel>
```

Comment: Please add your code what you have tried?

Comment: check post again

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you my solution, in my case I need to type in searchbox something and in that case when I type something RN sliding Up Panel should go back to bottom and to do that I used below

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
};

componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
};

_keyboardDidShow = () => {
    if (!this.state.bottomPanelHidden) {
        this._panel.hide();
    }
};

_keyboardDidHide = () => {
};
```

here you can get state of bottomPanelHidden as below

```
<SlidingUpPanel friction={50} avoidKeyboard={true} allowMomentum={true} allowDragging={true}
                draggableRange={{
                    top: deviceHeight,
                    bottom: 0,
                }} showBackdrop={false}
                onBottomReached={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        bottomPanelHidden: true,
                    });
                }}
                ref={c => this._panel = c}
                containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>


    ...render you body here...


</SlidingUpPanel>
```